# How can you find the indexes of the n least values in a vector?

Tags: r, vector

Is there a quick way to find the indexes of the n least values in a vector in R?

I know that to find the least value you can use `which.min(c(1, 5, 6, 4))`. Can this be extended?

Comment: you can use `sort(vect, index.return = TRUE)$ix[1:3]` or with `order` i.e. `order(vect)[1:3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments we shared either `order`

```
n <- 3
head(order(vect), n)
```

or with `sort`

```
head(sort(vect, index.return = TRUE)$ix, n)
```

#### data

```
vect <- c(1, 5, 6, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
which.nmin <- function(x, n){
    order(x)[seq_len(n)]
}

set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
which.nmin(x, 6)
# [1] 72 18 26 57 43  8
```